# Should I include interviews transcriptions in my thesis?

Tags: citations, thesis, formatting

In my PhD, I ran an experiment falling within the *grounded theory* framework, based on interviews I conducted. I transcripted them, tagged them, etc. This "enhanced transcription" is about 130 pages long (with pretty narrow margins).
I am now writing my thesis and **I wonder if I should include these transcription in appendix of my PhD thesis**.

My first guess would be yes, in order to enable contextualization when I quote snippets of theses interviews, but also for "open science" purposes (being honest about what I've done, archival purpose, reproducible research, etc.).

However, thesis in my field are usually ca. 150 pages long. Addind these transcriptions (i.e. 130 pages) would add a significant amount a pages with a low information density. A solution could be to display these transcripts in a very small font, so that they are only 50 pages long, but I don't think it's a good solution.

By the way, my supervisors don't have opinion about it, since using grounded theory is rather uncommon in my field - hence no "jurisprudence".

Comment: At the time of the interviews, did you discuss with interviewees how the material might be used? There are some major potential issues here with use of personal information, though hopefully you have already considered this aspect!

Comment: I've got their consent for audio-recording the interviews in order to transcribe it later. I was considering anonymizing any personal information (name, title of the project they worked on, and any hints that might make them recognizable), and asking again for formal authorization for publishing transcripts in their final form (i.e. sending them the file and asking "*is it ok for you to publish it in that form?*").

Comment: Despite the authorization you have currently, you probably need to go through IRB to get permission to change the way you are dealing with any data, not just getting consent again from the participants. IRB might also have opinions about your raw or transcribed data, and whether publication of material in that form is ever acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite honestly I doubt that anybody would go and read that appendix. What I would do is that once the thesis is approved and put in the online repository of the university, you could add this appendix just as an online document and refer to it in the main thesis. That way if anybody wants to access it they can.

Comment: I do agree that it's unlikely someone would go through these interviews! If I upload it online, how should I refer to it in my thesis? (i.e. when I quote a sentence, I'd like to say *"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" (cf. Project X, Participant Y, at time mm:ss)*. However I feel a bit dishonest if thesis reporters cannot access transcript at the time of their report...

Comment: @ebo you can still add an online file also when you submit the thesis, in the main text you will give a refence to the section of the appendix. If they want they follow the link you provide, what's the issue?